# VPN over proxy (global)

Tags: vpn, proxy

How to run VPN over (global) proxy on Android (with root and without)?

The situation: VPN service app doesn't provide proxy functionality, but proxy is necessary.

Comment: Possible additional context posted on Security.SE: [ISP-restricted VPN on Android](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/269568/59741)

Comment: I didn't figure out. I can set up some proxy implementation using certain apps from play market, but it doesn't work globally, like VPN mode. Yes, certain apps provide VPN functionality, but i don't want to use proxy as VPN. Instead, i wan to use VPN over proxy.